# how to do a sum of vertical levels

Tags: python, python-2.7, for-loop

I am trying to integrate over the depth my data. My data is a 4D data(341,50,120,100) where I have time, depth, i-pos, j-pos, respectively. I am trying to apply the following equation....

```
Vf[t,i,j] = integral ((mean - data[t,zz,i,j]) x mean) x ( depth[zz,i,j] - depth[zz+1,i,j])
```

where,

```
f = (mean - data)*mean

d_depth, i.e: abs(data[0,0,0,0]-data[0,1,0,0])
```

Thus,

```
Vf = integral(f*d_depth)
```

The way I am doing isn't that efficient at all, though.

```
for tt in range(sal.shape[0]):
    print('time',str(tt))
    for j in range(sal.shape[3]):
        print('j',str(j))
        for i in range(sal.shape[2]):
            print('i',str(i))
            for zz in range(sal.shape[1]-1):
                Vf[tt,i,j] += abs(grid[zz,i,j]-grid[zz+1,i,j])*f[tt,zz,i,j]
```

Would anyone know how to do this in a better way?

Thank you,

Matheus

Comment: sal would be my data, it's just because for me is salinity but I will have to do for other variables in my netcdf file.

Comment: What is `sal`'s **datatype**?  What is `grid` and what is its **datatype**? What is `grid`'s shape and what is `f`'s shape?

Comment: type(sal) = numpy.ma.core.MaskedArray and type(grid) = numpy.ndarray, grid.shape =  (50, 120, 100)

Comment: What is `f`'s shape and what is `Vf`'s final shape?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Divining from your code I am assuming that

- `f` has 4 dimensions: `tt`, `zz`, `i`, `j`
- `grid` has 3 dimensions: `zz`, `i`, `j`
- `Vf` has 3 dimensions: `tt`, `i`, `j`

Fake data:

```
TT = 5
ZZ = 3
I = 5
J = 4
grid = np.random.randint(0, 255, (ZZ, I, J))
f = np.random.rand(TT,ZZ,I,J)
```

The nested for loops can be *vectorized*:

`abs(grid[zz,i,j]-grid[zz+1,i,j])` is essentially [numpy.diff()](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.diff.html#numpy.diff) on the first axis which can be performed on the complete array without a loop.

```
term1 = np.absolute(np.diff(grid, axis = 0))
```

`term1`'s shape is (ZZ-1, I, J). In order to multiply it by `f`, the `zz` dimension needs to be the same so that the multiplication will [broadcast](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/user/basics.broadcasting.html) across `f`'s `tt` dimension/axis. From the innermost loop statement we see that the last element of `zz` isn't used - `for zz in range(sal.shape[1]-1):`.

```
w = term1 * f[:,:-1,...]
```

From `Vf[tt,i,j] +=` we see that the `zz` axis has disappeared so it is summing accros the `zz` axis.

```
vf = w.sum(axis = 1)
```

...

```
term1 = np.absolute(np.diff(grid, axis = 0))
w = term1*f[:,:-1,...]
vf = w.sum(axis = 1)
```

Running my fake data through your nested for loops:

```
Vf = np.zeros((TT,I,J))
for tt in range(TT):
##    print('time',str(tt))
    for j in range(J):
##        print('j',str(j))
        for i in range(I):
##            print('i',str(i))
            for zz in range(ZZ-1):
                Vf[tt,i,j] += abs(grid[zz,i,j]-grid[zz+1,i,j])*f[tt,zz,i,j]
```

And comparing `v` to `Vf` indicates that the result is the same:

```
>>> np.all(Vf == vf)
True
>>>
```

---

There are some *[einsum](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.einsum.html)* equivalents which can sometimes be faster.

`w = term1*f[:,:-1,...]` can be replaced with

```
w = np.einsum('ijkl, ijkl->ijkl',f[:,:-1,...], term1[None,...])
```

and `vf = w.sum(axis = 1)` can be replaced with

```
vf = np.einsum('wxyz->wyz', w)
```

Combining the operation to a single einsum produces noticeable *speedup*

```
vf = np.einsum('ijkl, ijkl->ikl',f[:,:-1,...], term1[None,...])
```

Comment: f shape is f = (mean - data) / mean but, Vf is gonna be (5,5,4) accordingly with your example.

Comment: @moehbon - Was it any faster?

Comment: it was way faster. It takes me 10 seconds to execute the commands above.